# Sumifs with Variable number of Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project to automate some reports. The requirements are to summary tables at differing levels (Country, Region, Salesperson, Product for example) that are nested. The number of levels will differ depending on the user and client. What I am struggling with is how to VBA to build sumifs where the number of parameters will not be known until the code is run.

```
Dim i as Long
Dim InSh As Object
Dim OutSh As Object
Set InSh = Workbooks("Readin").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OutSh = Workbooks("Output").Worksheets("Sheet1")

for(i in 2 to n)
OutSh.Cells(i, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Insh.Range(rng_0),Insh.range(rng_1) _ 
,"Criteria_1",.....,Insh.Range(rng_n,"Criteria_N")
next i
```

I would like to avoid having VBA write the formula in an Excel cell for two reasons. One, access to the underlying data is limited and will not be sent out in the file. The second is speed. I believe this way will be faster as with making these reports by hand there will be 1000's of these formulas created, on multiple sheets.

I've tried to feed the variables into the sumif statement by creating a string and array, but both times I received a mismatch error. The only solution that I can think of is a select case statement based on the number of criteria passed on, but that is limited to what I would program and I do not know how deep the criteria could become.

Comment: You can construct the `COUNTIFS()` as a string formula, but instead of inserting it to the worksheet, use the `Worksheet.Evaluate()` method to execute it.

Comment: I assume you meant `SUMIFS()`. That should work. In testing this, I noticed that  if I use this code:
'OutString = "SumIfs(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,""A"")"
    OutSh.Cells(1, 1) = Evaluate(OutString)
    OutSh.Cells(2, 1) = [OutString]`
I get different output. The first is a number the second is a string. I can use the first, but was wondering why there is a difference.

Comment: There are two different methods: `Application.Evaluate` (the default if you don't specify otherwise) evaluates in the context of the ActiveSheet: I would advise *not* using that method.  Typically the one you want is `Worksheet.Evaluate`.  For example  `Sheet1.Evaluate(...)` will evaluate the formula in the context of `Sheet1`, regardless of whether that sheet is active.